# Access to Watch Sensors

Tags: javascript, nativescript, wear-os

I'm trying to build a simple Wear OS app using Nativescript and want to access the heart rate sensor and send its reading via MQTT to a server. I know there is an MQTT plugin on nativescript, but I'm not sure as to how do I access the sensor and get its reading?

The Nativescript docs don't have a wearables sections unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get direct access to heart rate sensors in Watch, but you could read the heart rate using HealthKit.

Try [nativescript-health-data](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-health-data) plugin

```
tns plugin add nativescript-health-data
```

Comment: Is this the case only with heart rate sensors? Because other sensors like the Light sensor works using Nativescript.